# JavaScript: changing input value using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to do a very simple task but for some reason I can't do it.

basically I am using the if statement to change the value of an input field using javascript but it doesn't work!

this is my code:

```
if (document.getElementById("colour").value == "171515"){
    document.getElementById("colour").value = "db0000";
}

if (document.getElementById("colour").value == "db0000"){
    document.getElementById("colour").value = "171515";
}
```

and the HTML looks like this:

```
<input type="text" id="colour" name="colour" class="colour" value="171515"/>
```

so what i need to do is this:

I launch a page and the input field is on my page with the value of `value="171515"`, and then I press a button and that should change the value of the input field to `value="db0000"`, and then I press the button again, and it should change the value of the input button to `value="171515"` and I need to do the same steps as many times as I want.

currently, it seems like it gets into a loop action and thats why it doesn't change the value of input field! (correct me if i'm wrong).

any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

EDIT:

The javascript code above is executed like so:

```
$(params.addPplTrigger).bind('click', function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();

///////// THE CODE ABOBE WILL GO HERE///////////

}
```

Comment: Possibly button events may be the reason how you're executing it?

Comment: It's worth noting that you have two `if`s, one changes the value one way, the other changes it back. Use `if (condition) {...} else if (condition) {...}` or a simple `if (condition) {...} else {...}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just missing an `else`:

```
if (document.getElementById("colour").value == "171515"){
    document.getElementById("colour").value = "db0000";
}

else if (document.getElementById("colour").value == "db0000"){
    document.getElementById("colour").value = "171515";
}
```

---

What happens in your original code

Case 171515:

- first if condition evaluates to true, because the value is 171515
- value gets changed to db0000
- second if condition evalutes to true again, because the value is db0000 now
- value gets changed back to 171515

Case db0000:

- first if condition gets evaluates to false, because the value is not 171515
- the value remains the same
- second if condition gets evaluates to true, because the value is db0000
- value gets changed to 171515

So, in both cases you'd end up with 171515.

Comment: If there's only two possibilities (and one must be true) the `else if (condition)` can be replaced by a simple `else` (though not my down-vote).

Comment: WORKED. THANKS EVER SO MUCH. I up VOTED THE ANSWER .... I DON'T KNOW WHY SOMEONE DOWNVOTED IT!!!!

Comment: Ha well spotted (My initial comment was far too hasty!)

Comment: @DavidThomas well spotted

Comment: Yeah, I'm really curious at what happens in the brain of those reflex-downvoters at times... You're welcome, hope I helped you understand what was going on.

Comment: @DavidThomas That would change EVERYTHING except 171515 back to 171515, which is different from just changing db0000 to 171515. That would work if there are just those two cases, but I like to keep it more accurate. :)

Answer (score 0):

since you are doing :

```
if (document.getElementById("colour").value == "171515"){
    document.getElementById("colour").value = "db0000";
}
```

and then reverse

```
if (document.getElementById("colour").value == "db0000"){
    document.getElementById("colour").value = "171515";
}
```

so you are not able to see the change .use `else instead of second if.`

```
if (document.getElementById("colour").value == "171515"){
    document.getElementById("colour").value = "db0000";
}else{
    document.getElementById("colour").value = "171515";
}
```